# How can I stop a contenteditable div from overflowing?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I am working with a contenteditable div and I have set a height to it and have attempted to cut off the field once it reaches that height with `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: hidden;` but instead of hiding any of that text, it just overflows the the div. How can I fix this?

```css
#editor {
    height: 1100px;
    border: .5px solid gray;
    padding: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
#editor:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code to have a look at it

Comment: i just added the code

Comment: Your code does not have `overflow: hidden` in it... When I add it, it is cut off (https://jsfiddle.net/fndughpr/).

Answer (score 3):

Try `overflow-y: scroll` instead for `#editor`

```css
#editor {
    height: 1100px;
    border: .5px solid gray;
    padding: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#editor:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: This conflicts with the OP's desire to hide the text, not make the div scrollable.